# Inserting arguments into string

Tags: php, string, insert, printf

In PHP, inserting variables into a string can be done by using [`sprintf`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php). If I have two string variables `$a` and `$b`, they can be inserted into another string like this:

```
$string = sprintf("String containing %s two other strings %s", $a, $b);
```

Is there a function such that the string can specify the order of the variables inserted? Instead of specifying the format of the inserted variable, I would like to specify which variable to insert. For example like this:

```
$string = sprintn("String containing %2 two other strings %1 in opposite order", $a, $b);
```

This would be very useful in combination with [`gettext`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/), since translators would be able to change the order of the variables in the string. It could also allow for inserting the same variable multiple times, which can be useful.

Comment: Have you read the PHP docs for [sprintf()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) particularly examples #2, #3 and #4

Comment: I actually did not see those examples. Thanks! But still, I would prefer to not have to specify the format of the variables.

Comment: You don't want much do you? That's the recommended approach for a reason; if you want to change the way sprintf() itself works, you're likely to have to do so at core level.... not sure if the PHP version is a wrapper, but you're certainly going to have to learn a bit of C to do so.... the whole point of sprint() is that you do set a type mask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went for the following solution. By using [`strtr`](http://php.net/strtr) instead of [`str_replace`](http://php.net/str_replace) it has the advantage of not recursively replacing any occurrences of `%n` that may be present in the arguments.

```
function sprintn($format) {
   $args = [];
   for($i = 1; $i < func_num_args(); ++$i)
      $args["%$i"] = func_get_arg($i);
   return strtr($format, $args);
}
```

Comment: A comment explaining the down-vote would be very welcome, as I don't see how this post fails to answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a util to do it:

```
function sprintn($format,$args = array()){
 for ($i=1; i<=count($args); i++){
   $format = str_replace("%".$i, $args[i], $format);
 }
 return $format;
}
```

Comment: Your solution will only work for less than 10 elements in the array. I have submitted an edit to fix it.

Comment: My suggestion was rejected, with the verdict that it should have been posted as a comment or answer instead. Your solution does not work for elements numbered 10 or higher, as %1 in %10 will be replaced before %10 is replaced.

Comment: I am assuming you're the one who down-voted my answer, @PhuLuong. Would you care to explain why? The reason why I have accepted my own answer instead yours I have already stated in the previous comments. It would be nice if you could fix this limitation, since I was not allowed to fix your code through an edit.

Comment: Oh, sorry @MagnarMyrtveit  but i did not do that. I saw the problem in my answer

Comment: Oh, ok. Sorry for putting the blame on you, then! Have a good day :)